# Ping/Broadband QOS over time tool for mac

Tags: macos, ping, broadband

I work on the train using a mac tethered to my 3G mobile.  Connectivity drops out sometimes, but not enough to stop me from working.

Am thinking about switching phones, but before I do, I'd like to measure the "connectivity" of this current phone.  Am looking for a piece of software that could send periodic pings over time (say an hour), and report back on the quality of the service.  e.g. number of pings sent, number of failed pings, ping travel time over time etc.

Maybe I could run a ping, redirect into a file, and process using excel or something, but I was after something that could do that for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you continually run ping in terminal, when you choose to end it, it will give you some statistics such as the number sent, the number failed the average, max and minimum speeds, as well as max deviation and packet loss.
If you need more automation you could just write a script to automatically run ping for you and write the output to a text file something like every hour.